# Create an AWS Kinesis WebRTC signaling channel from the browser securely

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I'm doing WebRTC and I use AWS Kinesis Video Signaling channels.
The problem is, I have to provide the AWS credentials to the `KinesisVideo`, `SignalingClient`, and `KinesisVideoSignalingChannels`.

And all of this is happening on the client side (browser), which means anyone can just look at my AWS credentials, how do I create these channels in a secure way?